# Close Bot Framework ME action dialog from OpenUrl action

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am writing a messaging extension that uses an Adaptive Card in a custom action dialog with some actions.  A couple of those actions are OpenUrl actions that open to a deeplinked tab within teams, or to chat with the teams user.  The problem I'm running into is that once the user clicks the action, the ME dialog does not close and the correct action opens underneath the dialog.

Is there a way to close the ME dialog and execute the action, as once they've selected this they would be finished with the ME action.

As far as the JSON is concerned, I'm writing something like this as the action command in the adaptive card, using AdaptiveCardTemplating

```
{
   "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
   "id": "ChatWithUser",
   "title": "Chat with ${if(length(requester.first) > 0, requester.first, 'Requester')}",
   "url": "${chaturi}",
   "$when": "${length(chaturi) > 0}"
},
{
    "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
    "id": "ViewItem",
    "title": "Open Item",
    "url": "${uri}"
}
```

Comment: hmm as far as i know theres no option to close it :(

Comment: Sadly that's what I'm thinking as well, was hoping there would be some kind of workaround...

Comment: Anyone got an update to this?  Kind of stuck at the moment on this.

Comment: Well, the update is sort of what i wrote. Not possible.